# How to show moving direction React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, maps

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) package for location tracking and using Firebase. then how to show moving direction on map like if moving west my location turns into looking west. I didn't find anything like this. It's so new thing for me.

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.LOW_ACCURACY,
        stationaryRadius: 120,
        distanceFilter: 120,
        notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
        notificationText: 'enabled',
        debug: true,
        startOnBoot: false,
        stopOnTerminate: true,
        locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
        interval: 30000,
        fastestInterval: 30000,
        activitiesInterval: 30000,
        stopOnStillActivity: true,
        url: 'URL!',
        httpHeaders: {
            'X-FOO': 'bar',
        },
        postTemplate: {
            lat: '@latitude',
            lon: '@longitude',
        }
    })
```